# piecewise linear regression with varying number of knots (MARS, python package)

Tags: python, spline

I want to use piecewise linear regression to fit the data with the sum of linear functions that act only at specific regions and optimize not only coefficients of that functions but also the knots number. Found [Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/py-earth/content.html) and a package to use:  sklearn-contrib-py-earth...

Tried to install this package several times but failed with this ([pyearth package installation issue (need to use MARS on Python 3.10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566046/pyearh-installation-issue-need-to-use-mars-on-python-3-10))... Suppose the library is too old, but tried to run it even with Python3.9 - no success.

Are there any other Python packages to fit my data with a sum of linear functions - giving only max. number of knots?

Are there any packages (Python) or API for Python that we can use to do this type of regression?